# lop %in% over the columns of a data.frame

Tags: r

I'm in a situation like this:

DF1:

> ```
>   "G1"            "G2"  
>   SEP11          ABCC1      
>   214223_at      ADAM19     
>   COPS4          BIK 
>   ACE            ALG3
>   EMP3           GGH
> ```

DF2

> ```
>   "S1"            "S2"  
>   SEP11          0.1858      
>   ADAM19         0.131        
>   COPS4          0.1143 
>   ACE            0.119
>   GGH            0.1214
> ```

I would like to have the following output:

> ```
>   "G1"            "S2"        "G2"           "S2"
>   SEP11          0.1858      ADAM19         0.131         
>   COPS4          0.1143      GGH            0.1214
>   ACE            0.119
> ```

For the first column of the DF1 I tried the following code:

```
  DF1 = read.delim("...", header = T)   
  DF2 = read.delim("...", header = T)      
  INT = intersect(DF1$G1, DF2$S1)            
  dx = DF2$S1 %in% int            
  out = DF2[idx]    
  write.table(...)
```

Now, I would like to apply the "logic" of the simple code for one column of DF1, for all the columns of the DF1, not one by one in order to have the desired output.

How this can be done? Is there another easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command returns a list of data frames, one for each column of `DF1`:

```
lapply(DF1, function(x) DF2[na.omit(match(DF2[[1]], x)), ])


$G1
     S1     S2
1 SEP11 0.1858
3 COPS4 0.1143
4   ACE 0.1190

$G2
      S1     S2
2 ADAM19 0.1310
5    GGH 0.1214
```